# how to fix Undefined variable: collaborators in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

in My laravel app. I have form.blade.php file in collaborator folder of view file. collaborators/form.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #ccc;margin-left:15px;padding:10px;">
        <h4 class="page-header">
            Collaborators
        </h4>
        @if( $collaborators)
           @foreach( $collaborators as $collaborator)
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            <img src="{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->getAvatarUrl() }}" />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete" style="margin-top:5px;padding:4px;width:35px;"
                      data-action="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/collaborators/{{ $collaborator->collaborator_id }}"
                      data-token="{{csrf_token()}}">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <hr/>
           @endforeach
        @endif
```

it include with users.blade.php file in projects folder projects/users.blade.php

```
@include('collaborators.form')
```

but I got this error massages

```
Undefined variable: collaborators (View: C:\Users\Flex\Desktop\mati\resources\views\collaborators\form.blade.php)
```

Comment: Next to having a view, you also need to set somehow the variables for that view. That part is missing in your question but (from the error message) obviously necessary if only to tell you more.

Comment: what did you mean?

Comment: I mean: If you don't define the variable, it is undefined. The part where you define your variables is missing. But see the duplicate question, it looks like someone else had the exact same problem (and that question shows where to define the variables for the blade view)

Comment: I have not any controller for this?

Comment: No idea, technically you don't need a controller but where you invoke the templating that generates the error, there you need to pass the variables for the view (that is also called "defining variables").